# TCPDF Images are not showing

Tags: php, tcpdf

on localhost I dont have any problem with images. Unfortunatelly on production server images are not shown. I did set 777 permissions to /cache/ folder. Anyone have an idea why pictures are not showing? Or is it possible to disable cache?

```
        $img = file_get_contents('http://***/images/shop/logo.png');
        $this->Image('@'.$img, 12, 12, 45, 0, 'PNG', $this->contractor->web);
```

path to tcpd is /libs/tcpdf/tcpdf.php

I have setted 777 for /libs/tcpdf/cache

What Iam doing wrong? as I said it works on localhost

Comment: wrong path... what do you mean?

Comment: $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] is used as a prefix of path 

[this url may help you][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12423107/image-display-error-in-tcpdf

Answer (score 0):

did you check if you both server you can do this:

```
file_get_contents(__URL_AND_NOT_PATH_HERE__)
```

basically the first thing is to check an option called **allow_url_fopen**

Comment: At the same time, check that you are actually wanting to pull via HTTP, and not just by accessing the filesystem directly (which is what you actually want if the image is on the same domain).

Comment: I did a progress, i found out that image is stored into /cache/ folder but still is not displayed in pdf. So get_contents works and image exists. And cache/img_.... is accessible thru web browser

Comment: this doesn't answer the question/suggestion. if the image exists and it is accessible via URL it doesn't mean that file_get_contents should work. Did you try to debug this step by step? There is a difference between the URL to a file and the physical path to a file. Since you are using images on the same server you might want to use a path and not an url.

Comment: As I said cache is generated that means that TCPDF loads the image and saves it in cache that means file_get_contents work. I already setted constants K_PATH_CACHE and K_PATH_URL_CACHE, but images still are not in pdf. any other path settings for displating images in tcpdf are required ?

Comment: when i use local path, cache is not generated and image still not showed
$path = __DIR__.'/../../images/shop/logo.png';